# Finding out Age in Months and Years given DOB in a CSV using python

Tags: python, datetime, csv, replace

I making several adjustments to an automatically gennerated CSV report.  I am currently stuck on a part where I need to take a patient's DOB and convert that into an Age in Months and Years.  There is already a Column for age in the original CSV, and I've figured out how to convert the data in the DOB Column to find the Age in Days, however, I need to be able to convert that to Months/years and then also take that calculated value and replace the value in the current field.  The current field is a hand-typed string which has no real consistent formattin. The actual CSV has about 1700 rows and 18 column, and uses the standard comma to separate them, so I'm just makign up a shorter form for an example, and using indents to make it easier to see:

```
Last_Name   First_Name   MI   age                 DOB          SSN         visit_date
Stalone     Frank        P    62yrs 10 months     07-30-1950   123456789   05-02-2013
Astley      Richard      P    47years3mo          02-06-1966   987654321   05-03-2013
```

What I want should look like this:

```
Last_Name   First_Name   MI   Age       DOB          SSN
Stalone     Frank        P    62y10mo   07-30-1950   123456789
Astley      Richard      P    47y3mo    02-06-1966   987654321
```

EDIT: I realized I could jsut use the date.year and date.month to jsut subtract year and month, making those values much easier to find.  I'm editing my code now and will update it when I got it working, btu I'm still having trouble wiht the second part of my question.

My code so far:

```
import re
import csv
import datetime

with open(inputfile.csv','r') as fin, open(outputfile.csv','w') as fout:
   reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
   fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
   writer_clinics = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames, dialect="excel")
   writer_clinics.writeheader()

   for row in reader:
    data = next(reader)
    today = datetime.date.today()
    DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(data["DOB"], "%m/%d/%Y").date()
age_y = (today.year - DOB.year)
age_m = (today.month - DOB.month)

if age_m < 0:
    age_y = age_y - 1
    age_m = age_m + 12

age = str(age_y) + " y " + str(age_m) + " mo "
print (age)
```

So, I'm tryign to figure out how to write the age into the correct field in the outputfile.csv?

Update 2: Managed to get most of it to write, however, it is having errors with certain fields being left empty in the input file.  My boss also wanted me to make the age, dependant ont he actual date of the appointment.  my current chunk of code:

```
import re
import csv
import datetime

def getage(visit, dob):
    years = visit.year - dob.year
    months = visit.month - dob.month
    if visit.day < dob.day:
        months -= 1
    if months < 0:
        months += 12
        years -= 1
    return '%sy%smo'% (years, months)

with open('inputfile.csv','r') as fin, open('outputfile.csv','w') as fout:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    writer_clinics = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, dialect="excel")
    writer_clinics.writeheader()

    for data in reader:
        visit_date = datetime.strptime(data["visit_date"], "%m-%d-%Y").date()
        DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(data["DOB"], "%m-%d-%Y").date()
        data["Age"] = getage(visit_date, DOB)
        writer_clinics.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Seems simple. subtract the DOB year from the current year and add the DOB month number.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the DOB? The "Age" field already is in months and years. Couldn't you just use regex to parse the existing "Age" field and make it look exactly how you want?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yeah, I didn't even think about that. that is way easier.

Comment: @kevlar1818 many of the "Age" fields are also out of date.  this report is being generated weeks, sometimes months after the age is hand typed into the system. when I run this script on the report, my boss wants it to not only make sure the formatting is uniform, but also that the data is as up to date as possible.

Comment: @Owenlars2 I'm working on a solution and I'll post shortly.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the fix I made to get the years/months bit right, still trying to write it to the output file though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses [Mark Ransom's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16614616/857893) for getting the correct age. This populates the output CSV file as you requested in the question.

```
import re
import csv
import datetime

def getage(now, dob):
    years = now.year - dob.year
    months = now.month - dob.month
    if now.day < dob.day:
        months -= 1
        while months < 0:
            months += 12
            years -= 1
    return '%sy%smo'% (years, months)

with open('inputfile.csv','r') as fin, open('outputfile.csv','w') as fout:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    writer_clinics = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, dialect="excel")
    writer_clinics.writeheader()

    for data in reader:
        today = datetime.date.today()
        DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(data["DOB"], "%m-%d-%Y").date()
        data["Age"] = getage(today, DOB)
        writer_clinics.writerow(data)
```

NOTE: I used only the CSV files you provided above to test this code.

Comment: This mostly works, but i'm getting some errors, I think it mostly has to do with some of the data in the csv being wonky, I'll post the final script when i get it going (or ask for more help if it doesn't work rihgt in an hour or so. thanks though!

Comment: For starters, I'd recommend `try`/`except` blocks for catching mal-formed CSV errors and the like.

Comment: ok, firstly, I changed the script to fit the rest of my specific program.  this meant changing the input files, the hyphens int he date to slashes, and making sure the headings were exactly the same as they appear int he cvs. Secondly, I changed the 'while' to another 'if' and made sure it was not under the condition of the previous 'if'. The script runs fine until it his a line on the CSV where there are empty values (eg, unnamed baby,someone with out a middle initial), and then it crashes and gives 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found'.

Comment: other than that, it seems to be writing the file jsut fine.

Comment: @Owenlars2 what line in my code above does this happen on? Basically all you need to do is just put an `if not data[whatever]:` check before using anything and handle it that way.

Comment: @Owenlars2 Why did you unaccept my answer? Stack Overflow etiquette would be to open a NEW question for your NEW problem.

Comment: oh, sorry. still new here. i'll try that if not thing and if it stilld oesn't work, make a new question. thanks again.

Comment: figured it out, it all had to do with the other formatting changes I had made to my csv. (eg replacing all the " and # and other symbols)

Answer (score 4):

You can't convert days into years and months, since years and months have different numbers of days in them. You need to take the differences of the years and months themselves.

```
dob = datetime.datetime.strptime('07-30-1950', '%m-%d-%Y')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
years = now.year - dob.year
months = now.month - dob.month
if now.day < dob.day:
    months -= 1
while months < 0:
    months += 12
    years -= 1
age = '{}y{}mo'.format(years, months)

>>> print age
62y9mo
```

Comment: this also works, and i think it's a little cleaner than what i originally did.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [eGenix DateTime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/egenix-mx-base) package?:

```
>>> import mx.DateTime as dt
>>> a = dt.DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
>>> b = dt.DateTime(2013, 6, 17)
>>> x = dt.Age(b, a)
>>> x.years
13
>>> x.months
5
```

Comment: I didn't know about that, though My work comptuer won't let me go to that download site.  It's very picky :/  I figured out a built in solution to that part of my problem, thanks anyways though!